# New button created in javascript isn't doing what other pre set buttons are doing

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, gif

When a new button is created it isn't being picked up by the rest of the code

```
var topics = ["dog", "cat", "pangolin", "snake", "bird", "emu", "cow", "hedgehog"]

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btnAddSubmit").click(function() {
        var newAnimal = $("#addInput").val();
        topics.push(newAnimal);
        newAnimal = newAnimal.toLowerCase();
        $("#buttons").append('<button id="gif' + newAnimal + '">' + newAnimal + '</button>');
    });

    $("button").click(function() {
        var currentGif = this.id;
        if (this.id != "submit") {
            currentGif = currentGif.replace("gif", "");
            currentGif = currentGif.toLowerCase();
            var topicNum = topics.indexOf(currentGif);
            var myUrl = "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=" + topics[topicNum] + "&api_key=oaPF55NglUdAyYKwDZ0KtuSumMrwDAK9&limit=15";
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: myUrl,
            }).then(function(response) {
                console.log(currentGif);
                console.log(response);
                $("#gifLocation").empty();
                var gifURL = response.data[0].images.fixed_width.url;

                console.log(response.data.length);
                var gifNum = response.data.length
                for (var i = 0; i < gifNum; i++) {
                    $("#gifLocation").append('<div id=gifDiv' + i + '></div>');
                    gifURL = response.data[i].images.fixed_width.url;
                    var gifRateId = "gifRate" + i;
                    var ratingLocString = '<p id="' + gifRateId + '"></p>'
                    var ratingLoc = $(ratingLocString);
                    var rating =  response.data[i].rating;
                    var gifRating = "Rating: " + rating;
                    $("#gifDiv" + i).append(ratingLoc);
                    $("#" + gifRateId).text(gifRating);
                    var gifId = "gif" + i;
                    var gifImage = $('<img class=gif id=' + gifId + '>');
                    gifImage.attr("src", gifURL);
                    $("#gifDiv" + i).append(gifImage);
                }
            });
            console.log(currentGif);
        }
    });
});
```

What I'm trying to do is when the user creates a new button, that button will then work like the premade buttons. The premade buttons are supposed to display a few gifs.

What is happening is that after I create the new button, clicking on that button won't even console log the id of that new button.

Answer (score 1):

Your event listener `$("#btnAddSubmit").click` worked only with already created buttons. That is means your new buttons will be without this listener. If you want to add listeners to the new buttons, you must do something like:

```
// We are create event listener as a function for convenient use
var onButtonClick = function () {
    var currentGif = this.id;
    if (this.id != "submit") {
        currentGif = currentGif.replace("gif", "");

        // Your code here...
    }
}

$("#btnAddSubmit").click(function() {
    var newAnimal = $("#addInput").val();
    topics.push(newAnimal);
    newAnimal = newAnimal.toLowerCase();
    $("#buttons").append('<button id="gif' + newAnimal + '">' + newAnimal + '</button>');

    // We are remove all button's listeners and at once add new
    $("button").off('click').on('click', onButtonClick);
});

// And this code will add your listener as it was originally
$("button").off('click').on('click', onButtonClick);
```

**Be cearful** if your buttons have another event listeners. If it exists, you connot use `.off()`. In that case is correct way will be add listener for a new specific button's id.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question and the `js` code provided, i guess this is because the newly added button doesn't get the event.
All events are attached to the dom on page load. The new buttons that are injected to the DOM doesn't get the events. jQuery already did the bindings to DOM elements before the new code was injected. To solve this you have to use `'.on()` method in jQuery

Something like this

```
$(document).on('click','your_button_class_here',function(){
    dosomething();    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `ready` callback, so all of this runs when the DOM is ready. However, you don't actually create the new button until this `ready` callback has already run! So when you try to add callbacks with `$("button").click(function(){})`, you are trying to add that callback to all the buttons on the DOM... but some of the buttons you want to add it to *do not exist yet*. They won't exists until that first button's click callback is executed! So the first button you make will have the callback attached, but the new ones will not.

Maybe try something like this? I expect something will be wrong with how the value of `this` works on your `click` callback, but I think it's a nudge in the right direction.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btnAddSubmit").click(function () {
        var newAnimal = $("#addInput").val();
        topics.push(newAnimal);
        newAnimal = newAnimal.toLowerCase();
        $("#buttons").append('<button id="gif' + newAnimal + '">' + newAnimal + '</button>');
        // be wary of what the value of `this` refers to! it might refer to 
        // the `this` of the scope in which it was defined!
        function gifCallback() {
            var currentGif = this.id;
            if (this.id != "submit") {
                currentGif = currentGif.replace("gif", "");
                currentGif = currentGif.toLowerCase();
                var topicNum = topics.indexOf(currentGif);
                var myUrl = "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=" + topics[topicNum] + "&api_key=oaPF55NglUdAyYKwDZ0KtuSumMrwDAK9&limit=15";
                $.ajax({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: myUrl,
                }).then(function (response) {
                    console.log(currentGif);
                    console.log(response);
                    $("#gifLocation").empty();
                    var gifURL = response.data[0].images.fixed_width.url;

                    console.log(response.data.length);
                    var gifNum = response.data.length
                    for (var i = 0; i < gifNum; i++) {
                        $("#gifLocation").append('<div id=gifDiv' + i + '></div>');
                        gifURL = response.data[i].images.fixed_width.url;
                        var gifRateId = "gifRate" + i;
                        var ratingLocString = '<p id="' + gifRateId + '"></p>'
                        var ratingLoc = $(ratingLocString);
                        var rating = response.data[i].rating;
                        var gifRating = "Rating: " + rating;
                        $("#gifDiv" + i).append(ratingLoc);
                        $("#" + gifRateId).text(gifRating);
                        var gifId = "gif" + i;
                        var gifImage = $('<img class=gif id=' + gifId + '>');
                        gifImage.attr("src", gifURL);
                        $("#gifDiv" + i).append(gifImage);
                    }
                });
                console.log(currentGif);
            }
        };
        // reference the new button by its ID and add your desired callback
        $("#gif").click(gifCallback)
    });
});
```